# Result from math calculation is not showing up on screen

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to make a simple android app that calculates the diameter of a sonar signal. The user inputs the depth(in meters) and angle(in degrees) and the app inputs the information into the formula: 
2.0 * depth * Math.tan(angle / 2.0)

So I have created the UI and the java code and when I go to run the app in a VM it loads, I enter numbers in to test it, and when I hit the calculate button it does nothing. I am new to java and android development in general so if anyone could shed some light that would be great.

Here is the [MainActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/enporter/5c6238d0d81afaa13de9f473cd327c87)

XML file for the UI widgets [activity_main.xml](https://gist.github.com/enporter/80bef3f89c2240838aab4a0472f42ba9)

I suspect the problem is something to do with this code that includes the formula but I am not sure so any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
double depth1 = Integer.parseInt(depth.getText().toString());
                double angle1 = Integer.parseInt(angle.getText().toString());
               double result1 = 2.0 * depth1 * Math.tan(angle1 / 2.0);
                result.setText(valueOf(result1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does nothing because you have added onClickListener on TextView instead of the Button here:

```
result.setOnClickListener(...)
```

You just need to change it to this:

```
// instance of your button
cal.setOnClickListener(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the clicklistener of your `result` view, that is why the value is not displayed on clicking on the `cal` view (calculate button). Try the following.

```
    cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //converting the user input from a string to an integer for calculation
            double depth1 = Integer.parseInt(depth.getText().toString());
            double angle1 = Integer.parseInt(angle.getText().toString());
            double result1 = 2.0 * depth1 * Math.tan(angle1 / 2.0);
            result.setText(String.valueOf(result1));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

We use setOnContextClickListener to register a callback to be invoked when this view is context clicked. If the view is not context clickable, it becomes context clickable.

So, as mentioned above, insteasd

result.setOnClickListener(...)

use

cal.setOnClickListener(...)

Please refer:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnContextClickListener(android.view.View.OnContextClickListener)